# Image Recognition Car parts

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have access to quite a large database of car parts.
The data is typical online shop data with description, pictures, attributes...

I would be interested in the following:
Is it possible to train a neural network to recognise car parts?
How many picture would I need apprx. for each car part?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to start is using a pretrained model and a technique called transfer learning. This method generally starts with a very robust model that was originally trained to recognize a large number of different objects (that may or may not include car parts). The final layer(s) of the original model are replaced with new untrained layers appropriate for the type of classification you're doing. These few layers are then trained on the new classification task (car parts in your case). A good tensorflow tutorial on this is given [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining).

Given that you have a large database of car part images which are already labeled, you're probably going to be able to (re-)train a fairly robust model. But without knowing more details about the database it is difficult to say for sure how many images you need for each part. If you just want to distinguish between very different types of parts like batteries and pistons, you'll need very few training images per part (e.g. a few). But if you're trying to distinguish between parts of the same type with minor differences you'll likely need many more training examples per part (e.g. tens or hundreds). This latter case is known as fine-grained recognition -- you'll find a lot of references on the web for this topic.